# PHP mysqli prepare query fails (delete)

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

This delete query fails and am not getting a reason why. The same query executes perfectly in phpmyadmin.

```
$stmt = $conn -> prepare('DELETE FROM restaurant_staff WHERE id = ? AND restaurantid IN (SELECT restaurantid FROM `restaurant_staff` WHERE staffid=?)')

$stmt -> bind_param('ii', intval($restaurantStaffId),intval($staffID));
$stmt -> execute();
```

Comment: please check the php logs

Comment: What do you mean fails? Are you getting an error message? I can't see anything wrong here.

Comment: Prepare statement returns false. But when the AND part of the query is removed (DELETE FROM restaurant_staff WHERE id = ?), it works. I don't understand it either.